# Why wasn't Officer Angela Lopez questioned when she killed a suspect?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-rookie

In **S01E08** of **The Rookie** episode: '**Time of Death**', Officer John Nolan kills a suspect for drawing a gun towards him. After this incident he had to go through a series of questioning by several officers higher up.

[image]

In **S01E20** of **The Rookie** episode: '**Free Fall**', Officer Angela Lopez does the same thing on a bus to prevent a bio attack.

[image: enter image description]

Why wasn't Officer Angela Lopez questioned on her actions? Is this because she is not a rookie?

Comment: I've not seen the show, but the weapon she's using in that image doesn't look standard issue (i.e. it's not something a police officer would just be carrying on the street every day). It's possible she was acting in a specific capacity in that situation and/or had been authorised to shoot to kill the suspect before doing so. That's a totally different situation to having to draw and fire your gun in self-defence.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist  No she wouldn't carry it on the street as a matter of course but I understand "tactical" weapons like that ARE carried in the police cars for events such as this, usually in a locked cabinet in the vehicle's trunk/boot. - Wikipedia *"due to the North Hollywood incident, qualified officers were issued patrol rifles called UPR (Urban Police Rifle) consisting mainly of AR-15 variants chambered in .223 after being certified from LAPD Urban Police Rifle School."*

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's my understanding that **ALL** shootings by LAPD officers are subject to a review by the Force Investigation Division

> Force Investigation Division (FID) is responsible for the investigation of all incidents involving the use of deadly force of an LAPD officer
>
> [Source](http://www.lapdonline.org/use_of_force)

Clearly Nolan, as a rookie, would be under much greater scrutiny than a fully-fledged police officer; but **Lopez's actions would also be reviewed but since the suspect was a clear and present danger to others and was, in fact, about to kill another officer, the investigation would be a matter of form.**

**The fact that we do not see the review doesn't mean it didn't take place.**

We see the investigation of Nolan's shooting because that's the focus of that episode.

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but I was wondering, as I read the question: Was it explicitly stated that she didn't have to answer a bunch of questions a bit later on, or was it simply *not mentioned,* one way or the other, and the after-action review easily could have happened "between scenes"?

Comment: If the review was routine and involves writing of papers and some panelists that fully expects there to be no wrong doing, it will be really boring to watch. It's like an every-day version of the office... I wouldn't want to watch that.

Comment: @Lorendiac exactly, these situations are only shown when they add some value to the story or help with character development somehow.